# XML retornando valores incorretos

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Estou tentando fazer um programa no [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) para testar os códigos necessários para conseguir rodar um [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), ler seus dados e inseri-los em uma lista. Mas para isso, eu preferi utilizar um `MessageBox` para fazer o debug primeiramente.

Meu [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) é um `RSS Feed` que eu baixo diretamente do meu Tumblr pro dispositivo do usuário (no caso, um computador). Estou utilizando o `XmlDocument` pra abrir o arquivo e utilizar o `GetElementsByTagName` para pegar os valores.

Como gambiarra, eu acabo pegando o título do Tumblr **iPoema** e sua descrição **Residência de obras de poetas amadores. Há leitores online**, pois eles utilizam as mesmas tags dentro de **item**. Também gostaria de saber se tem como fazer `XmlNodeList` pegar as tags que estão dentro da *Child* **item**.

**EDIT**

Esqueci de mencionar que eu estou com problemas de retorno na parte de `category` do meu [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), pois ele retorna, mesmo que eu comece por `i = 0`, como se o valor inicial fosse `-1` e ao chegar em `20` ele fica vazio.

**EDIT 2**
Resolvido.

**frmHome.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace iPoema_CSharp
{
    public partial class frmHome : Form
    {
        string FULLPATH, tipo;
        string tempFolder = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\";
        string[] titulo = new string[21];
        string[] texto = new string[21];
        string[] autor = new string[25];
        public frmHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void download(string url, string filename)
        {
            filename = tempFolder + filename;

            // Apaga o arquivo antigo
            File.Delete(filename);

            // Baixa o arquivo
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile(url, filename);
            }
            FULLPATH = filename;
        }

        private void readXML(string path)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);

            // Title
            XmlNodeList titleList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    titulo[i] = titleList[i].InnerText;
                }
            }

            // Description
            XmlNodeList descList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("description");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    texto[i] = descList[i].InnerText;
                }
            }

            // Category
            XmlNodeList catList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("category");
            for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
            {
                autor[i] = catList[i].InnerText;
            }
        }

        private void bAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            download("http://www.ipoema.tumblr.com/rss", "iPoema.xml");
            readXML(tempFolder + "iPoema.xml");

            string text;

            for (int x = 1; x <= 19; x++)
            {
                text = texto[x];
                text = text.Replace("</p>", "\n");
                text = text.Replace("<p>", "");
                text = text.Replace("<br/>", "\n");
                text = text.Replace("&#8217;", "'");
                text = text.Replace("&#8220;", "\"");
                text = text.Replace("&#8221;", "\"");
                MessageBox.Show(text + "\n\n#" + autor[x], titulo[x], MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Link:** [iPoema RSS](http://ipoema.tumblr.com/rss)

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <description>
            Residência de obras de poetas amadores.Há leitores online
        </description>
        <title>iPoema</title>
        <generator>Tumblr (3.0; @ipoema)</generator>
        <link>http://ipoema.tumblr.com/</link>
        <item>
            <title>Mente absurdamente louca</title>
            <description>
            <p>Este sou eu,<br/>todo fodido que nem eu não há,<br/>olha pro céu e pro mar,<br/>muitos dizem que me entendem,<br/>mas será que eles vivem como a gente?</p> <p>Poderia até ser uma vida legal,<br/>mas será que o amor pode ser natural?<br/>Só penso nisso todos os dias,<br/>sei que não sou as mil maravilhas,<br/>mas pense que, em um dia,<br/>já obteve vontade de nós termos uma vida, querida?</p> <p>Nascido para morrer sozinho, nunca,<br/>mas também não morrerei sofrendo nesta espelunca,<br/>toda suja de sentimentos vazios,<br/>todos nós estamos perto do rio<br/>das lamentações, onde não há multidões<br/>querendo lhe julgar por não saber ainda o que é namorar.</p> <p>Me sinto alienado nesse sentido abstrato,<br/>muito errado esses loucos controlados,<br/>mídia filho da ****,<br/>controlando os amigos nessa vida estúpida,<br/>toda inculta, vivendo sem conduta,<br/>tomando multa, na sua fuça retardada,<br/>momentos loucos com sua vida idolatrada,<br/>que nem momentos como estes serão lembrados,<br/>nem honrados pelos seres humanos movidos pelo pouco que lhes é dado.</p>
            </description>
            <link>http://ipoema.tumblr.com/post/80971539116</link>
            <guid>http://ipoema.tumblr.com/post/80971539116</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 28 Mar 2014 10:13:37 -0300</pubDate>
            <category>Alexandre de Souza</category>
        </item>
        [...]
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Eu suggeria que ficas familar com os metodos do [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) para ajudar ler RSS. [traduzido](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seleção por nome de etiqueta (*tag name*) é sempre perigosa porque pode-se cair em casos como este em que elementos com o mesmo nome de etiqueta têm significado diferente.

Neste caso `/rss/channel/description` não tem o mesmo significado de `/rss/channel/item/description`.

Para efetuar uma consulta mais precisa vais ter de usar [XPath](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Para obter as descrições dos itens tenta algo como isto:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("http://www.ipoema.tumblr.com/rss");
foreach(XmlElement node in xml.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/description"))
{
    // processa o nó
}
```

Mas dado que se trata de um tipo conhecido de documento XML, apoio a recomendação do **mdisibio** para a utilização da classe [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx).